# Auto unzip files & deploy to Heroku from Github

Tags: github, heroku, deployment, unzip

I have a simple PHP + SQlite app working on Heroku with this structure:

```
myPhpApp/
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── data
│   ├── css.css
│   ├── small_db.sqlite3
│   ├── large_db.sqlite3.zip
└── index.php
```

The Procfile file simply contains: `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2`

Since my Github account limits file size, so I have to zip **large_db.sqlite3** to **large_db.sqlite3.zip** .

What Inam trying to do is to auto unzip **large_db.sqlite3.zip** back to **large_db.sqlite3** when I deploy it to Heroku through Github action.

So far I saw this code snippet:

```sh
# From https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-heroku

name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master # Changing the branch here would also work

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.7.8 # This is the action
        with:
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
          heroku_app_name: "YOUR APP's NAME" #Must be unique in Heroku
          heroku_email: "YOUR EMAIL"
```

Is it possible to do something like this (pseudo code) in Github Action?

```sh
cd ./data
unzip large_db.sqlite3.zip 
cd ..
deploy/build (on Github/Heroku)
```

May you all be well and happy!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a process of trials & errors, I came to this solution.

I shared it here for future visitors. May it be helpful.

Github action yml file: **.github/workflows/main.yml**

```yaml
# From: Github action template
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

# Controls when the action will run. 
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Unzip and remove zip files
      - run: unzip -qq './data/*.zip' -d ./data && rm ./data/*.zip
      - uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.7.8 # This is the action
        with:
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
          heroku_app_name: "YOUR APP's NAME" #Must be unique in Heroku
          heroku_email: "YOUR EMAIL"
```

**Note**:

- For each zip file (separated zip files should be more flexible for your later updates, try not to bundle all in one big zip file), for my case, I compressed each file with this command: `zip large_db.sqlite3.zip large_db.sqlite3`
- `heroku_app_name` is the **appname** in your https://**appname**.herokuapp.com